# Matrix calculation (in R) - least squares

Tags: r, matrix, linear-regression, least-squares

I have a matrix in R as per the following:

```
(72 -- 90 -- 60)
(60 83 -- -- --)
(50 -- 77 83 --)
(-- 40 -- 84 65)
```

Reproducible as follows:

```
B = matrix(c(72,60,50,NA,NA,83,NA,40,90,NA,77,NA,NA,NA,83,84,60,NA,NA,65),nrow=4,ncol=5)
```

It is a sparse matrix in the sense that not all elements are populated. What i want to do is find an adjustment matrix (or vector, that is added to each column) so that the average of the rows is equal to the average of columns. The answer is:

```
(13.04, 10.93, -14.68, -22.70, 5.90)
```

I computed this iteratively and is also rounded to 2dp so doesn't quite equate, but, for example, it should be the case that if you add the adjustments to the original matrix:

```
A = t(t(B)+c(13.04,10.93,-14.68,-21.70,5.9))
```

then the average of the row averages should equal the average of the column averages:

```
mean(colMeans(A, na.rm = TRUE, dims = 1))
mean(rowMeans(A, na.rm = TRUE, dims = 1))
```

However, I think this is a least squares problem and can be solved algebraicly but i don't know how to do it or how to set it out. The question is, is there a way to find the adjustment algebraicly using matrix calculation rather than iteratively. Can anyone help?

Comment: On Stack Overflow (especially in the `r` tag) please have your data in a *reproducible* format, such as by putting the code to re-create your data or using `dput()`.

Comment: You may also want to provide a link to the subject that you're referring to. It's not clear to me (even after a google search and several quantitative degrees) what you're talking about, possibly due to the specific terminology you're using.

Comment: How is the adjustment matrix mathematically connected to the sparse matrix?

Comment: Hi, thanks for comments. Have edited question to include some R code and hopefully a more thorough explanation of the adjustment matrix.